# difficulty in applying texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am trying to apply texture in my snowman's scarf but its not applying correctly . I am adding a picture for your refence. Kindly and check let me know the problem . Please help. Thank you all.[image]

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? That stretched part? In that case you have bad UV map that needs to be updated

Comment: As @MikoCG says, it's just a bad UV map so you'll need to re-unwrap your mesh.

Comment: thank you it is done